# Tidy Data Layout - convert variables into factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data table

```
| State | Prod. |Non-Prod.|
|-------|-------|---------|
|  CA   | 120   |   23    |
|  GA   | 123   |   34    |
|  TX   | 290   |   34    |
```

How can I convert this table to tiny data format in R or any other software like Excel?

```
|State | Class    | # of EEs|
|------|----------|---------|
| CA   | Prod.    | 120     |
| CA   | Non-Prod.| 23      |
| GA   | Prod.    | 123     |
| GA   | Non-Prod.| 34      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df,id.vars='State')
#     State  variable value
# 1   CA         Prod   120
# 2   GA         Prod   123
# 3   TX         Prod   290
# 4   CA    Non-Prod.    23
# 5   GA    Non-Prod.    34
# 6   TX    Non-Prod.    34
```

Comment: I got an error: could not find function "melt", but plyr is installed, any idea why :(

Comment: Sorry, I meant `reshape2`.

Comment: I actually used "melt(data)" and it did the trick. But if I use the argument "id.vars='State'", it actually gave me 'N/A's for prod. and non-prod...

Comment: Here is the final code: `map2 <- melt(map, id=c("City","State","Country")) `. Thanks!

Comment: It should work, unless your column name isn't really `State`.

Comment: When I used the final code, it actually added a new column with sequential numbers. You think that is causing the column to shift by 1?